# Model choice: multilevel vs. linear model with interaction

Tags: regression, r, mixed-model, multiple-regression, panel-data

I have a panel dataset and my dependent variable is the logit-transformed share of farm workers on long-term contracts. I am particularly interested in the effect of pastoral focus in agriculture, represented by variable pastoral. The difficulty is that the impact of this variable changes over time. I have two models, one is multilevel and the other is a linear regression with interaction between pastoral and year:

```
model1 <- lmer(logitshare ~ pastoral + other variables + (pastoral | year), 
               data = mydata)  
model2 <- lm(logitshare ~ pastoral + other variables + pastoral : factor(year), 
             data = mydata)
```

The outputs of the models are similar. I wonder what is the difference between them. i.e. what is the advantage of a more sophisticated multilevel model over a basic lm?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the dynamic effect of the pastoral variable in time, which I would be, it is better to have the interaction between pastoral and time as a fixed effect rather than a random effect. Therefore I would go with model 2 rather than model 1.

Comment: Thank you! Could you be a bit more specific: what is the dynamic effect, and how can I see it?

Comment: A significant interaction between ```time``` and ```pastoral``` means that the effect of pastoral differs according to time i.e. is dynamic in time.